# Cassandra pool warning displaying continuously

Tags: clustering, python, cassandra

I am using the [Cassandra driver for python](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html) in Spyder. I am trying to fetch some data from Cassandra table. Here is my code:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster=Cluster(['some_ip'])
session=cluster.connect('some_key_space')
df_filtered_10m=session.execute("some query")
```

This is all working fine and I am getting the desired results. The problem is that in the console, this message is continuously popping up:

> WARNING:cassandra.pool:Error attempting to reconnect to 10.0.10.91,
>   scheduling retry in 256.0 seconds: [Errno None] Tried connecting to
>   [('10.0.10.91', 9042)]. Last error: timed out

I have tried `cluster.shutdown` but it not working as well. 
How to get rid of it?

Comment: I also get the same warnings. I am using version 3.11.2 of cassandra, have installed it on AWS EC2 and accessing it via Python driver. I do get results back but frequently still get the warnings above. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you see this IP in the output of `nodetool status` on the one of the cluster nodes?